# Can't edit the "Read more" option at this Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this theme and when I want to add the "Read more" option using the "Insert More Tag", the theme adds a read more icon below. What I want to do: remove the "read more" icon and show the "read more" at the end of the text (not below the text -- this is important). Please check the visual instruction below.

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm really grateful.

(p.s. I know very little how to edit html files, if not at all)

Visual instruction --> http://bit.ly/V8fU8k

Theme --> http://bit.ly/13I3x7U

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to solve the problem? We can *help* you solve it, but we aren't free-of-charge rent-a-coders; you can't just link us to a file and expect someone to do your work for you for free. That's not the way SO works. Post up some examples of code and what you've got so far, and you'll receive some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can change the Read More option in loop.php file in your theme folder

    Remove this code

    <?php if (option::get('display_readmore') == 'on') { ?><span class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?></a></span><?php } ?>

   find

   <?php if (option::get('display_content') == 'Full Content') {  the_content(''); } else { the_excerpt(); } ?>

and add code after this

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?></a>
```

Comment: Hi! I removed <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?></a>. How can I add something after it, because I already removed it. Didn't understand clearly probably.

Comment: You said remove : <?php if (option::get('display_readmore') == 'on') { ?><span class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?></a></span><?php } ?>, -------BUT  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more', 'wpzoom'); ?></a>. --------is part of the line I deleted.

Comment: UPDATE: Just did it right now (as you advised). But the problem is the "Read more" appears below the paragraph and not at the end of the last sentence. Is it possible? Thank you for your help indeed.

Comment: Hello Ankit! Yes, that worked! Thanks. How can I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please replace in loop.php file in your theme

<?php if (option::get('display_content') == 'Full Content') {  echo get_the_content(''); } else { echo get_the_excerpt(); } ?>

to 

<?php if (option::get('display_content') == 'Full Content') {  echo get_the_content(''); } else { echo get_the_excerpt(); } ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e('Read more'); ?></a>

This will help you to put read more near end of the post.
```